# Why is Postgres talking about column 0; and what does it mean?

Tags: javascript

While trying to add a new subject to the subjects table, Postgres thinks I want to add something to columns 0, 1, and 3. Why?

I'm posting a new user with Postman. In the user routes, I am inserting the user object in the user table. That works.

My second step is to insert the subject in a `subjects` table if that subject does not exist yet.

That is where things go wrong.

This method should insert a new subject in the `subjects` table and return the new row:

```
    insertSubject(knex, newSubject) {
        return knex
            .insert(newSubject)
            .into('subjects')
            .returning('*')
            .then(rows => {
                console.log(rows)
                return rows[0]
            })
    },
```

Instead of doing so, I'm getting this message in Postman:

```
{
    "message": "insert into \"subjects\" (\"0\", \"1\", \"2\") values ($1, $2, $3) returning * - column \"0\" of relation \"subjects\" does not exist",
    "error": {
        "length": 122,
        "name": "error",
        "severity": "ERROR",
        "code": "42703",
        "position": "25",
        "file": "parse_target.c",
        "line": "1034",
        "routine": "checkInsertTargets"
    }
```

For reference, this is how I'm calling the above method:

```
    .post(jsonParser, (req, res, next) => {
        const { first_name, last_name, email, user_password, gender, tutor, student, fee, in_person, online_medium, subjects } = req.body;
        const userFields = { first_name, last_name, email, user_password, gender, tutor, student, fee, in_person, online_medium, subjects };
        const newUser = { first_name, last_name, email, user_password, gender, tutor, student, fee, in_person, online_medium };

        for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(userFields)) {
            if (value === null) {
                return res.status(400).json({
                    error: { message: `Missing ${key} in request body` }
                })
            }
        }

        const user = []
        UsersService.insertUser(
            req.app.get('db'),
            newUser
        )
        .then(res => {
            user.push(res)
            return SubjectsService.getBySubject(
                req.app.get('db'),
                subjects
            )
        })
            .then(res => {
                //console.log logs the subject I posted with postman
                console.log(subjects)
                if (typeof res === 'undefined') {
                    return SubjectsService.insertSubject(
                        req.app.get('db'),
                        subjects
                    )
                    .then(res => {
                        console.log("hihi")
                    })
                }
            })
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response)
                res
                    .status(201)
                    .location(path.posix.join(req.originalUrl, `/${user[0].id}`))
                    .json(serialize(user))
            })
            .catch(next)
    })
```

This is the object I sent through Postman:

```
        "first_name": "Felicio",
        "last_name": "Heading",
        "email": "fheadi0@nyu.edu",
        "user_password": "5u2v1E1BKrct",
        "online_medium": true,
        "in_person": true,
        "student": false,
        "tutor": true,
        "gender": "Male",
        "rating": 1,
        "fee": 25,
        "subjects": "abc"
       }
```

Edit: I'm only attempting to enter `subject` in the subject table.
`subjects` evaluates to `abc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error:

```
"insert into \"subjects\" (\"0\", \"1\", \"2\") values ($1, $2, $3) returning * - column \"0\" of relation \"subjects\" does not exist"
```

The reason is that you are telling Postgres that the table has columns "0", "1", and "2"  that you want to `INSERT` `values ($1, $2, $3)` into. The error is telling you those columns don't exist in the table. Actually it stops at column "0" as it makes no sense to go any further. Best guess is you are assigning the values you which to `INSERT` to the column list.

Comment: Please help me understand why Postgres thinks I'm telling it that the table has columns "0", "1", and "2"

Comment: Take a look at:http://knexjs.org/#Builder-insert. I don't use Knex, but I think your insert code is not correct. Also what is value of newSubject? I'm guessing it has 0,1,2 as keys and they are being used as columns.

Comment: I updated my question to make it clearer. As I wrote there, the value of subjects is in this case 'abc'.

Answer (score 0):

As @AdrianKlaver noted in a comment, I needed to change the insert code. I updated it like so:

```
    insertSubject(knex, newSubject) {
        return knex('subjects')
            .insert({subject_name: newSubject})
            .returning('*')
            .then(rows => {
                console.log(rows)
                return rows[0]
            })
    },
```

And it works!